# axios.post.then is called triggered after everything else

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am trying to create a project where a person can create a question and an answer. I am using laravel and Vuex.

I would like to create a variable called Question_id with the response.data after I have called the axios.post to create the question. I would then like to call a function with this Question_id.

I am now noticing though that I cannot do this because when I try to set the question_id variable in .then portion of my axios.post, it happens after I call the other function. In other words, the .then portion happens after all my other code has ran.

```js
qaForm(){
  axios
    .post("/api/question/create", this.questionForm)
    .then(response => {
      question = response.data;
      question_id = question.id;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.response);
    });

  addQuestion(question_id);
}
```

I can confirm this my consoling.out different steps. If I run this experiment:

```js
qaForm(){
  console.log("before axios post"); // runs 1st

  axios
    .post("/api/question/create", this.questionForm)
    .then(response => {
      console.log("inside axios.then"); // runs 3rd

      question = response.data;
      question_id = question.id;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.response);
    });

  console.log("after axios post"); // runs 2nd
  addQuestion(question_id);
}
```

I receive:

```
before axios post
after axios post
inside axios.then
```

Why is it this way? Am I making any mistakes? What are some possible workarounds?

Comment: the axiost request is asynchronous. so when you log `after axios post`, in reality it should be `after axios post was initiated but hasn't received the response yet`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axios requests are asynchronous, and as such return a promise. That is why the code within `then()` is executed after the code that is below.

the simple fix is to move the code inside the response handler

```js
qaForm(){
  console.log("before axios post"); // runs 1st

  axios
    .post("/api/question/create", this.questionForm)
    .then(response => {
      console.log("inside axios.then"); // runs 2nd

      question = response.data;
      question_id = question.id;

      console.log("after axios post"); // runs 3rd
      addQuestion(question_id);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.response);
    });
}
```

This may seem a little strange when you first see it, it is my preferred way of dealing with asynchronous functions.

The JavaScript language however introduced `async-await` functionality that would allow you to rewrite the code in a way that you might find more intuitive though.

Note the use of `async` and `await` in the code.

```js
async q0aForm() {
  console.log("before axios post"); // 1st

  let response = await axios.post("/api/question/create", this.questionForm)
  console.log("no more axios.then"); // 2nd

  question = response.data;
  question_id = question.id;

  console.log("after axios post"); // 3rd
  addQuestion(question_id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually ended up using your first suggestion. At first I felt like it was bad practice, but i understand now the necessity for it!

Comment: _"I felt like it was bad practice"_ 
Not at all, Promises took me a while to fully comprehend

Answer (score 0):

I saw your previous code, and everything is working right since is an axios petition. you could try for example in your store something like this.

```
async actionStore(){
    const response = await axios.post('/api/question/create', this.questionForm;
    if(isok){
     //commit to store
     return something;
    } else return some error;  
}
```

then in your method inside your component try this.

```
qaForm()
        {

            actionStore().then((response)=>{
                if(response isok)
                 addQuestion(question_id);
             });


        }
```

It's just an example, cause I can't see all your code right now
remember that actions from store return promises.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can private message you more if you would like to. I appreciate it!

Comment: sure, this is the basic Idea but if you keep struggling you can send me more info.

Answer (score 0):

If your using '.then' with POST, that my choise.

```
const blaBla = () => {

  const POINT = '{YOUR POINT URL}'
  const URL = '{YOUR POST VARIABLES}'
  axios({
    url: POINT,
    data: `producturl=${URL}`,
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  }).then((res) => console.log('res', res.data.content))

}
```

end worked

```
blaBla()
```